# using google map v2 or v3 in android application?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am making a project on tourist  guidance system on android. I wanted to include google maps in my application and wanted to know whether to use google maps API v3 or v2? Also, I cannot find any tutorial that tells me how to include v3. Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Google Maps API V2` is the native version of Google maps, while Google Maps API V3 is new API for web development, you could use the API V3 and embed it into a `WebView`, but if you want to achieve the best result you should use Google Maps API V2 for Android.

Here a blog guide I wrote on how to embed Google Maps API V2 in your application that you can use to get started:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: Hey, Thanks! But when i try running the app in phone it displays the message that cannot find the parser. Any idea how can i get it resolved?

Comment: I never encountered this problem, could you open a new question with it's all description?

Comment: hey, just solved that problem.It was due to  usage of android phone having gingerbread whereas the app is build for ice cream sandwich

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the Maps API for Android is v2, v3 is for the web.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 1):

> Google Maps API v2 provide specific api for android.
>
> Wih the api for web development ,Google Maps API v3 has been designed to load quickly and work well on mobile devices. In particular, focused on development for advanced mobile devices such as Android and iOS handsets.[googlemap#mobile](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Mobile)

use google map v3 in android with webview and javascript interface.

Here [google map v3](http://javazerosign.blogspot.in/2013/11/google-map-v3-for-android-devices.html)  a blog guide I wrote on how to use Google Maps API V3 in your android application.

Answer (score 0):

In 2013 v2 is valid but now v3 is latest for android map check below thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41549359/2888952