# Google map showing blank Screen Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using all permission but i am getting black screen of google map. The following code i am using for showing map in my activity. I have set all the permissions in manifest. I am using 23 Api level . Thanks

MainActivity :

```
try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

        // Changing map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            // Show rationale and request permission.

        }

        // Enable / Disable zooming controls
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

        // Enable / Disable my location button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Compass icon
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        // lets place some 10 random markers
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // random latitude and logitude
            double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                    longitude);

            // Adding a marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                    .title("Hello Maps " + i);

            Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                    + randomLocation[1]);

            // changing marker color
            if (i == 0)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (i == 1)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            if (i == 2)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
            if (i == 3)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            if (i == 4)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            if (i == 5)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
            if (i == 6)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            if (i == 7)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
            if (i == 8)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            if (i == 9)
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
            if (i == 9) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (permissions.length == 1 &&
                permissions[0] == android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        } else {
            // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

/**
 * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
 */
private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

    return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
            longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
            150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
}
```

My App is not crashing but i am getting this error in the logcat :

```
05-05 15:19:39.811 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : opening's messed  up, /sys/devices/platform/galcore/gpu/gpu0/gpufreq/scaling_governor Permission   denied
05-05 15:19:39.811 129-555/? E/PHService: GpuOperator    : int       android::GpuOperator::setScalingPolicy(android::sp<android::GpuUnitParam>&),   check failed!!!!
 05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421    Rev.6376 
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: This is decoding
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: decoding stream->hasLength()
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: Qmage parsing for decoding ok
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 99    Width() : 77 sampleSize : 1
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: normal image decoding
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame call : QM
05-05 15:19:40.032 908-908/? E/Qmage: onDecode : return true QM
05-05 15:19:40.122 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : opening's messed     up, /sys/devices/platform/galcore/gpu/gpu0/gpufreq/scaling_governor Permission     denied
05-05 15:19:40.122 129-555/? E/PHService: GpuOperator    : int         android::GpuOperator::setScalingPolicy(android::sp<android::GpuUnitParam>&),     check failed!!!!
 05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421   Rev.6376 
 05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: This is decoding
05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: decoding stream->hasLength()
05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageDecParseHeader call : QM
05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: Qmage parsing for decoding ok
05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: onDecode :  QmageHeader.NinePatched 0
05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageHeader Height() 72 Width() : 72 sampleSize : 1
 05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: normal image decoding
 05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame call : QM
 05-05 15:19:40.212 730-730/? E/Qmage: onDecode : return true QM
 05-05 15:19:40.232 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : opening's messed  up, /sys/devices/platform/galcore/gpu/gpu0/gpufreq/scaling_governor Permission denied
 05-05 15:19:40.232 129-555/? E/PHService: GpuOperator    : int   android::GpuOperator::setScalingPolicy(android::sp<android::GpuUnitParam>&), check failed!!!!
  05-05 15:19:40.392 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : writing's messed up: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online, -1, Invalid argument
 05-05 15:19:40.392 129-555/? E/PHService: CpuOperator    : int android::CpuOperator::setCpuOnlineStatus(unsigned int, int*), check failed!!!!
05-05 15:19:40.392 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : opening's messed up, /sys/devices/platform/galcore/gpu/gpu0/gpufreq/scaling_governor Permission denied
 05-05 15:19:40.392 129-555/? E/PHService: GpuOperator    : int      android::GpuOperator::setScalingPolicy(android::sp<android::GpuUnitParam>&), check failed!!!!
 05-05 15:19:40.392 625-625/? E/MotionRecognitionService:   mReceiver.onReceive : ACTION_USER_PRESENT  :: UNLOCK SCREEN
 05-05 15:19:40.422 908-908/? E/Launcher: Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
 05-05 15:19:40.512 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : writing's messed up: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online, -1, Invalid argument
 05-05 15:19:40.512 129-555/? E/PHService: CpuOperator    : int android::CpuOperator::setCpuOnlineStatus(unsigned int, int*), check failed!!!!
 05-05 15:19:40.512 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : opening's messed up, /sys/devices/platform/galcore/gpu/gpu0/gpufreq/scaling_governor Permission denied
 05-05 15:19:40.512 129-555/? E/PHService: GpuOperator    : int  android::GpuOperator::setScalingPolicy(android::sp<android::GpuUnitParam>&), check failed!!!!
  05-05 15:19:40.562 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : opening's messed up, /sys/devices/platform/galcore/gpu/gpu0/gpufreq/scaling_governor Permission denied

  05-05 15:19:46.848 2493-2493/? E/SPPClientService:       [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
  05-05 15:19:46.848 2493-2493/? E/SPPClientService: [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] PackageName :      googlemap.harry.com.googlemapintegratesample, true, false
05-05 15:19:46.848 2493-2493/? E/SPPClientService: [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] Ignore Replacing case
 05-05 15:19:47.058 970-970/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
  05-05 15:19:47.058 970-970/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid            package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
  05-05 15:19:47.899 970-970/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
  05-05 15:19:47.899 970-970/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
   05-05 15:19:48.350 18757-18757/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
  05-05 15:19:48.350 18757-18757/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
 05-05 15:19:48.700 129-555/? E/PHService: SysfsAccess    : opening's messed up, /sys/devices/platform/galcore/gpu/gpu0/gpufreq/scaling_governor Permission denied
```

I am using folling permissions in Android Manifest :

```
package="googlemap.harry.com.googlemapintegratesample">

<permission
    android:name="googlemap.harry.com.googlemapintegratesample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="googlemap.harry.com.googlemapintegratesample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="googlemap.harry.com.googlemapintegratesample.MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Please attach logcat. Propably you have invalid token.

Comment: Repalce com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment with com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment and check if it works

Comment: No this is not working but i have solved now , after two hours wasting my time i found that my internet is not working but thanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the following permissions or meta data tag for API key

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my api key"/>
```

```js
<permission
        android:name="com.yourpkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
          android:name="com.yourpkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.yourpkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Also make sure you have added the API key in manifest
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my api key"/>

Comment: i am using everything Just see above

Comment: Please post your layout file

Comment: Have you enabled the 'Google Maps Android API' on Google developer console?

Comment: i have added xml layout above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753411/using-google-map-v2-or-v3-in-android-application