# Google Map Api v2 shows "V/GoogleSignatureVerifier : signature not valid" error message in log

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am developing an Android application using `google map api v2` to show a Map in a Fragment. When I run the application, I always got this error message poppin in my log every now and then.

Things I've tried:

- Erasing the debug.keystore and rebuilding the app.
- Downgrading the Google Play Service and upgrading it again.
- Deselect Offline Work

Nothing does the trick so far...

Once upon the time in the Log tab :

```
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.app-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.android.app-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000000/n/armeabi
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is armeabi-v7a
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
    2364-3928/com.example.android.app D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 154 Google release certificates
    1921-2130/? V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.example.android.app signature not valid.  Found: 
                                              MIIB3TCCAUYCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzEWMBQGA1UEAwwNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzEQMA4G
                                              A1UECgwHQW5kcm9pZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMwHhcNMTYwNTE3MTYxNzM0WhcNNDYwNTEwMTYxNzM0
                                              WjA3MRYwFAYDVQQDDA1BbmRyb2lkIERlYnVnMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdBbmRyb2lkMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
                                              UzCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAkafVu0j1zuB6+cpo6q5OsfhrlEFzVknFNs0c
                                              vJorrlTTPZK3WSmkX9jZ0cp6oL60+4mHPouAR7Hq72gAs8u9Zh3eVrnV7uP7Rv2/z84DJuo34z1g
                                              lahfkNPR/mCsYkK+ZqkC6uR46NnoftoKC/9vJSlUxYaBLT+mWvApz4rUKuMCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG
                                              9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAERId+C7AD5Ew4Jv4mTmaZWBUtkinCKFSF4RtVa3xnHjL5xDPbAEq829gt+yx7
                                              FkftGZO1x5nWEdAWyxiZgET3sKyl4ejRu1V5qvTMOcPMaVHw/e5v97FK8q756tQBcAu+Zs77P6MW
                                              RxXtAwqeIkV1+L1rY8WueawfQ7Wbm1bPOg==
    1921-2130/? V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.example.android.app signature not valid.  Found: 
                                              MIIB3TCCAUYCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzEWMBQGA1UEAwwNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzEQMA4G
                                              A1UECgwHQW5kcm9pZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMwHhcNMTYwNTE3MTYxNzM0WhcNNDYwNTEwMTYxNzM0
                                              WjA3MRYwFAYDVQQDDA1BbmRyb2lkIERlYnVnMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdBbmRyb2lkMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
                                              UzCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAkafVu0j1zuB6+cpo6q5OsfhrlEFzVknFNs0c
                                              vJorrlTTPZK3WSmkX9jZ0cp6oL60+4mHPouAR7Hq72gAs8u9Zh3eVrnV7uP7Rv2/z84DJuo34z1g
                                              lahfkNPR/mCsYkK+ZqkC6uR46NnoftoKC/9vJSlUxYaBLT+mWvApz4rUKuMCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG
                                              9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAERId+C7AD5Ew4Jv4mTmaZWBUtkinCKFSF4RtVa3xnHjL5xDPbAEq829gt+yx7
                                              FkftGZO1x5nWEdAWyxiZgET3sKyl4ejRu1V5qvTMOcPMaVHw/e5v97FK8q756tQBcAu+Zs77P6MW
                                              RxXtAwqeIkV1+L1rY8WueawfQ7Wbm1bPOg==
    1921-2130/? V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.example.android.app signature not valid.  Found: 
                                              MIIB3TCCAUYCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzEWMBQGA1UEAwwNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzEQMA4G
                                              A1UECgwHQW5kcm9pZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMwHhcNMTYwNTE3MTYxNzM0WhcNNDYwNTEwMTYxNzM0
                                              WjA3MRYwFAYDVQQDDA1BbmRyb2lkIERlYnVnMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdBbmRyb2lkMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
                                              UzCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAkafVu0j1zuB6+cpo6q5OsfhrlEFzVknFNs0c
                                              vJorrlTTPZK3WSmkX9jZ0cp6oL60+4mHPouAR7Hq72gAs8u9Zh3eVrnV7uP7Rv2/z84DJuo34z1g
                                              lahfkNPR/mCsYkK+ZqkC6uR46NnoftoKC/9vJSlUxYaBLT+mWvApz4rUKuMCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG
                                              9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAERId+C7AD5Ew4Jv4mTmaZWBUtkinCKFSF4RtVa3xnHjL5xDPbAEq829gt+yx7
                                              FkftGZO1x5nWEdAWyxiZgET3sKyl4ejRu1V5qvTMOcPMaVHw/e5v97FK8q756tQBcAu+Zs77P6MW
                                              RxXtAwqeIkV1+L1rY8WueawfQ7Wbm1bPOg==
    1921-2130/? V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.example.android.app signature not valid.  Found: 
                                              MIIB3TCCAUYCAQEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwNzEWMBQGA1UEAwwNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzEQMA4G
                                              A1UECgwHQW5kcm9pZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMwHhcNMTYwNTE3MTYxNzM0WhcNNDYwNTEwMTYxNzM0
                                              WjA3MRYwFAYDVQQDDA1BbmRyb2lkIERlYnVnMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdBbmRyb2lkMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
                                              UzCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAkafVu0j1zuB6+cpo6q5OsfhrlEFzVknFNs0c
                                              vJorrlTTPZK3WSmkX9jZ0cp6oL60+4mHPouAR7Hq72gAs8u9Zh3eVrnV7uP7Rv2/z84DJuo34z1g
                                              lahfkNPR/mCsYkK+ZqkC6uR46NnoftoKC/9vJSlUxYaBLT+mWvApz4rUKuMCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG
                                              9w0BAQUFAAOBgQAERId+C7AD5Ew4Jv4mTmaZWBUtkinCKFSF4RtVa3xnHjL5xDPbAEq829gt+yx7
                                              FkftGZO1x5nWEdAWyxiZgET3sKyl4ejRu1V5qvTMOcPMaVHw/e5v97FK8q756tQBcAu+Zs77P6MW
```

## UPDATE

**I'm still having the error message, does anyone fix it since then?**

```
/com.example.android.greenLeaf V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                                      MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                                      EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
                                      bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
                                      MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
                                      FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
                                      cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
                                      LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
                                      dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
                                      sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
                                      URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
                                      qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
                                      gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
                                      VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
                                      A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
                                      4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
                                      zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
                                      yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
                                      KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
                                      Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
                                      MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
```

Comment: try this lib............  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

Comment: I already have that lib... :(

Comment: Probably same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208647

Comment: @Pang This doesn't make my application crash so It's probably not the same... Or if it is, the other issue is wrong

Comment: as someone from google mentioned in his answer on this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-google-play-services-9-0-0

it seems to be a bug with the library.

Comment: Did you fix it ? I have the same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018234/no-marker-displayed-on-the-map-with-google-play-services-version-9-0-83). I tried to fix this by downgrading Google Play Services manually then adapting dependencies after downgrading Google Play Sevices but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Issue Still there :(

Comment: Are you using latest google play services version 10.0.1?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently it's a known issue acknowledged by a google developer
stating this in a more recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379789/1435985):

> Sorry, thats a bug! It's just spurious logging though: Google Play
>   services does some checking to see whether you are a Google app or a
>   regular third party one.
>
> As part of that, it calls the signature verifier and the logging ended
>   up more verbose than intended - it will be fixed in a future
>   version.This shouldn't affect the behavior of your app at all.

So it should just be ignored until the future update...

Answer (score 16):

When You make signed apk then **you have to put SHA-1 Of that keystore** in Google Api console where u enabled GoogleAPI V_2 enabled.Then **Generate API key** again and put that **API key into your manifest file**.

Answer (score 6):

By checking the internet for the other people who encountered the same problem of yours, in updating Google Play Service to 9.0.83. I found a discussion [here](http://www.discuzfeed.com/code/loezsopu-android-app-is-crashing-due-to-v-googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid.html) on how to solve that problem. You can try to check it, if it can help you.

Some solution is by checking if you have enabled offline work for gradle, deselect Offline Work if it's checked. Then, confirm if you have latest version of Google services mentioned as dependencies in project level `build.gradle`: `classpath com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0`. Clean and build the project after the gradle sync completes.

Try to update the SHA1 key in your project on Google Developer Console and update the Maps API key in your android project.

Also, some people fixed it by just deleting the debug.keystore file found in the android folder.

Comment: I didn't specified a fingerprint and a package name to my API key at the first place... So it shouldn't be restricted anyways

Comment: how to update SHA-1 key in Google Developer Console? that console page is so complicated

Answer (score 5):

Add this in project level gradle file:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'`

and this one for module level gradle file:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

and move below plugin at the end of file (at last line) of module level gradle file:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score 5):

As per Ian Barber's comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333220/googlesignatureverifier-signature-not-valid-message-google-play-services-9-0-0/37379789#37379789) answer Google Play services version 10.0.1 will fix this issue.

> Updgrade to the latest version (10.0.1 last time I looked), should go
>   away.

Hope this will help you.

Happy coading!!!

Answer (score 3):

Gnah. This was bugging me for hours! Just deinstall the updates of Google Playservice 9.0.83. Version 8.7.02 is working here. Also keep this posting in mind: https://plus.google.com/+ChristopheBeyls/posts/LC2XCSoaVBJ

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed it by deleting the debug.keystore file found in the .android folder.
It will generate automatically and create new SHA1 using that file.

Comment: Ok and what do I do with that new SHA1? Because i've tried that and still, nothing happens. DO I have to generate a new Key for the Map API?

Comment: Add that SHA1 to google developer console where you have added previously old one SHA1. If you are not added than follow the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#if-you-are-using-the-standard-google-maps-android-api

Answer (score 2):

you should change Map api v2 to v3 :- [Map API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2tov3) coz of Version 2 of the Google Maps JavaScript API is no longer available. This guide is intended to help developers who are already using the Google Maps JavaScript API v2 migrate their code to version 3.